# Electric field inside a conductor is zero

Tags: electrostatics, charge, home-experiment

My professor has stated that the electric field inside a conductor is 0.I understand this

However, he has also said that even if the conductor has some hole in it, **the electric field inside this hole is also 0**

Now, two examples which confuse me:

Consider a thick spherical shell with radiuses $a,b$. Now, let there be a point charge q **outside the shell**. It is said the the electric field inside the shell is $0$ due to the reason above.

However, if we move the charge to the center of the shell, it is said that the electric field inside the shell is $\displaystyle\frac{kq}{r^2}$, which is different than $0$.

I am quite confused. Is the statement only correct when there are no charges inside the hole?

Another quick question: If the shell isn't thick, is the electric field inside still 0 for the first example? I believe it is but am not sure.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31163/10635

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a charge inside, you have a field.
2. the shell is usually rather thin or even only a net. Look for "Faraday cage" in wikipedia.

Comment: And if I don't have a charge, I don't have a field?

Comment: yes, the charge on the shell or outside does not give a field inside, So in a car you are secure from lightening.( but the outside could get charged)

Answer (score 0):

(a) "the electric field inside a conductor is 0." True if, but only if, there are no moving charges in the conductor. For example if there is a current in a wire, then there *is* an electric field in the wire and vice versa.

(b) "Is the statement only correct when there are no charges inside the hole?" Correct.

(c) "If the shell isn't thick, is the electric field inside still 0" Yes, if there are no moving charges.